# how to build go outside of source directory?

Tags: go

My go application directory structure is like this:

```
/app
  go.mod
  go.sum
  main.go
```

When I build the app I usually cd into that directory and build.

```
cd app
go build
```

I wonder if I can build without cd in to app directory.
When I go `go build /app`, it prints `go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'`.

Comment: Your `go.mod`  and `go.sum` files should be at the root of your project, and then you'll be able to run `go build /app` without any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://golang.org/ref/mod#commands-outside :
`go build` needs to be run from a module directory.

The simplest way is to `cd` into your module directory (`cd /app`) to run your `go build` command.

---

(there probably is some way to create a phony local `go.mod` file, and reference your `/app` module from there, but I wasn't able to devise a hack to do this)

Answer (score 9):

Go now can change directory before build with the help of flag `-C`:

`go build -C app`

"The go subcommands now accept -C  to change directory to  before performing the command"
Source: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20

*(You don't need to run `cd ..` after this command. Shell stays in the same directory)*

Comment: Note that the `-o` flag is still interpreted relative to the dir you give `-C`, not to the working directory as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure to build you will need to be in the app directory.

As a workaround if you are just wanting to be on the command line in a different directory and want to run the build with one command you can just chain the cd and go build commands together like this:

```
cd app; go build ; cd ..
```

This is the same amount of typing but could be in your command history just a couple presses of the up arrow away.

Note this is for bash or similar UNIX style shell. If using Windows cmd then I think it would be something like this (Not tested as I don’t have readily available access to a Windows machine right now):

```
cd app & go build & cd ..
```